# Кнопка не удаляется

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Код:

```
from tkinter import*

def b():
    global c
    global a
    a.destroy()
def c():
    global b
    a=Button(text='ddd', command=b).grid()
c()
mainloop()
```

Почему не удаляется? И тогда как удалить эту кнопку в **функции**?

Comment: Потому что в переменную a у вас записывается не кнопка, а результат вызова метода grid() - а это всегда None. Нужно разделить создание кнопки и размещение через grid.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь по-другому это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

В переменную `a` у вас записывается не объект `Button`, а результат вызов метода `grid`, а т.к. этот метод ничего не возвращает, то записывается `None`. Нужно разделить запись объекта в переменную и размещение с помощью `grid` на отдельные строки. Также нужно переменную `a` объявить глобальной в функции `c`, чтобы она была доступна из функции `b`:

```
from tkinter import *


def b():
    a.destroy()


def c():
    global a
    a = Button(text='ddd', command=b)
    a.grid()


c()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!

Comment: Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым.